# Get dropdown name instead of value when editing user

Tags: php, mysql, editing

I am in need of some help, I have a table where it shows the people that have signed into a patient program.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Right now if you look in the Location column, it says 8 instead of the last option in the dropdown being Manalapan.

Here is how the database table looks for offices location:

[image]

I would like to grab the office_name data from the database while retrieving the patient information in the table,from the table patients:

[image]

It is stored in the database as pat_loc and this one is 8.

In the end, I want it to say the name of the office, not the number it is stored at, first getting it from the patient table then going to the office table for the name.

Is there such a thing that can be done?

If needed, I will show my current code to see where it needs to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing an inner join so you can grab all the data you need from both tables

```
SELECT * FROM patients INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc
```

And then accessing it through your row array like `$row['office_name]`

Comment: Here is how my current code looks like: 
pastebin.com /WP5NiU1S

Comment: @user2533499 I don't think you posted anything, you could do an edit on your question and post the code there.

Comment: Edited :) pastebin.com /WP5NiU1S

Comment: I tried that, and the table column is now blank. Should I change the query used in: `$getval = mysql_query("SELECT office_name FROM offices WHERE office_id = " . $row['pat_id'] . "");`

Comment: @user2533499, mmhm weird, that looks all right, so you were getting the id number when you made that query?

Comment: Yeah, I get the value from **patients** table, I want it to get the value from **patients** then go to **offices** table, match it based on the **office_id** and return and echo the **office_name**.

Comment: @user2533499 I think it should be like this '$getval = mysql_query("SELECT office_name FROM offices WHERE office_id = " . $row['pat_loc'] . "");

Comment: It still seems to show a blank box when I updated the code to the JOIN that you did. pastebin.com /ZZdLZmzu

Comment: @user2533499 if you did the join you should be able to access the variable directly in the row like $row['office_name']

Comment: One more thing, I am also trying to get the insurance company name. How do I add another table and field name to the INNER JOIN query.

Patient has insurance company name as **pat_ins** stored as a number

Insurance table has id of insurance company as **ins_id** and the name as **ins_name**

How do I add it so it gets the id and prints out the name from insurance table?

Comment: I did `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patients INNER JOIN offices, insurance ON office_id = pat_loc AND ins_id = pat_ins")`

but that didnt seem to work.

Comment: @BrianCherdak it would be like $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patients INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc INNER JOIN insurance ON ins_id = pat_ins"). And remember to accept the answer :)